Allow bounties to be posted with the API
Currently, as far as I can tell, it is not possible to post a bounty on an answer through the SE API; indeed, that seems to be just about the only thing the API doesn't let apps do to questions. Is it possible to post bounties with the API, and if not why is that the case?

Why do you want to do that? It's not something one is bound to do automated unless bountying all their rep away in a careless manner.

One of the main reasons I value the write access I have via the API is for moderation purposes via userscripts, which bundle bulk actions into less clicks. For example, casting a flag and downvoting via the API when I find a non-answer, all in one click. Or, here on Meta, casting a close vote, casting a delete vote, and posting a comment on a "Lost Soul" question. I cannot view a use-case for posting a bounty more easily via the API, except if I wanted to do it robotically, in which case I'd be doing so without much regard for the actual content, which... Isn't a "healthy" use of a bounty.

My use-case for this is something like a browser extension which allows a human to bounty a question through its UI, not an automated tool for handing out bounties. My impression from the API docs was that such uses are the intended purpose of the write endpoints.

Worth to mention, this wasn't possible even with the official SE apps.

I personally think that this feature isn’t strictly necessarily for a few reasons:

IMHO if a user can’t even be bothered to manually visit the site, they clearly haven’t put enough consideration into dishing out a bounty in the first place.

You did mention your use case, as “something like a browser extension which allows a human to bounty a question through its UI”.
But, and correct me if I’m mistaken, I don’t see how this is any different to simply visiting the site manually, to place the bounty?

In the occasion that the API malfunctions, bounties could be accidentally placed, and even though this is unlikely, the consequences would be huge.

Apart from your use case, I don’t really see any other real need for this feature.


And I really mean no offence, it’s a good idea, I just think it’s simply not worth the hassle.

Well - there's a few folks working on alternative android apps - so 1. isn't such a far fetched thing.

@JourneymanGeek That is indeed a fair point, that I hadn't considered. But then again, maybe when such android apps become big enough, they will release the bounty feature anyway. For now, I still hold my opinion that it isn't worth it. But of course that could change.
